# Switch to full image view in Android

Tags: android, tabs, imageview

I have a tab layout set up and I would like to temporarily replace the whole screen with an image view and then go back when the image view is held.  How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would start another activity with just the ImageView as startActivityForResult.  Not sure what you mean by "when the image view is held", but when the user pushes back it would finish and go back to your tab activity.

Comment: I meant to ask, can you pan and zoom in an image view?  If not, how can I allow the user to do that?

Comment: You probably want to check out gestures: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html